# wicket checkbox AttributeAppender

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox, wicket, onchange

In a code that I am working on there is a normal(no ajax) `checkbox` to which I want to append the JavaScript `onchange` event to it like:

```
checkbox.add(new AttributeAppender("onchange", Model.of("func(this);"), ""));
```

There is also an`AjaxEventBehavior("onclick")` added to the `checkbox`.

The function that must be called by `onchange` event is called just once even I check and uncheck the `checkbox` multiple times. I am guessing this has to do with the 'ajax' 'onclick' event.

How to make the `func(this)` called whenever the `checkbox` checked or unchecked?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can call your `func(this);` function as a `AjaxEventBehavior. getPreconditionScript()` or `getSuccessScript()`, instead of adding and `AttributeAppender` on the `onchange` event.

Take a look at 
http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.html#getPreconditionScript()

Your `AjaxEventBehavior` will look similar to this:

```
new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

     protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
             System.out.println("ajax here!");
     }

     protected CharSequence getSuccessScript() {
             return "func(this);";
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have indeed considered this. But instead looking at getSuccessScript() or getPreconditionScript() I was trying to do something in onEvent() method, like calling the func(this), but I didn't know how. So I still don't know how to implement what you are suggesting. Can you please show an example on how to use getPreconditionScript(), getSuccessScript() or onEvent() so I can call the javascript func(this) method?

Comment: thank you very much, I have just tested it and it does exactly what i want. I guess it is ok to just neglect the onEvent method?

Comment: So you mean that now you have two `AjaxEventBehavior` both attached to `onclick` event?

Comment: No, one `AjaxEventBehavior` is attached to `onclick` event and the other one to 'onchange' event. In the `onchange` case I just left the `onEvent` method empty but `override` the `getSuccessScript` method. So my question was, is it ok to leave the `onEvent` method empty?

Comment: Well I think that it's ok but a bit strange to leave the `onEvent` empty. I was thinking to only use `onclick` event, so may be you can join this two `AjaxEventBehavior` in only one attached to `onclick`. I don't now last versions of Internet Explorer, but old versions don't fire `onchange` event as expected. Check this site: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com.es/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html

Comment: In this case you make a server call, wasting network for nothing. I suggest you put the javascript by overriding `onComponentTag` if the `AttributeAppender` is not working. Another solution would be using the `AjaxCallDecorator` to call `func(this)` overriding the `decorateScript` method.

Comment: @jordeu, leaving the 'onEvent' method empty is strange and as Cedric stated it it is also wasting of network, so it is not OK to leave it empty. I can confirm that 'onchange' doesn't work properly in ie7 and ie8 but it does work ok in ie9. So I will join the two 'AjaxEventBehavior' in one 'onclick' event. Thank you.

Comment: @CedricGatay, thank you for your comment. As you may have noticed I am new to Wicket. Could you please provide some examples of 'AjaxCallDecorator' or 'onComponentTag' specific to a 'checkbox' in a 'Panel'?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding my comments on the other answer, here is what I suggest using an `AjaxCallDecorator`

```
new AjaxEventBehavior('onclick'){
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      //call your onclick handling logic here
    }

    protected IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator(){
      return new IAjaxCallDecorator(){
         public CharSequence decorateScript(Component component,
                        CharSequence script){
            //prepend your javascript call to ajax server call
            return "func(this);"+script;
         }
         public CharSequence decorateOnSuccessScript(Component component,
                                 CharSequence script){
            return script;
         }
         public CharSequence decorateOnFailureScript(Component component,
                                 CharSequence script){
            return script;
         }
      };
    }
}
```